# Compare files from a list

Tags: shell-script, file-comparison

I have got a file list (<10) as output of some command. For example:

```
$ find foo* -name bar*Test.groovy

foofoo/foo-tasks/src/test/groovy/foo_main/store/barEarthTest.groovy
foo-co/foo-tasks/src/test/groovy/foo_main/store/barMercuryTest.groovy
foo_ba/foo-tasks/src/test/groovy/foo_main/store/barMarsTest.groovy
foo_tr/foo-tasks/src/test/groovy/foo_main/store/barMarsTest.groovy
foo_P1/foo-tasks/src/test/groovy/foo_main/store/barJupiterTest.groovy
foo_P2/foo-tasks/src/test/groovy/foo_main/store/barTatooineTest.groovy
```

I would like to know which of these files are identical and which are different. I do not care what exact difference is.

What is the way to get this information in more convenient form?

Answer (score 5):

There are several codes that do much of this work for you, for example: *fdupes* *jdupes* *rdfind* *duff*

A few years ago I posted comparison runs of fdupes and rdfind at http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/programming-scripting/195467-find-same-size-file.html#post924892

Here are some details about these 4:

```
fdupes  finds duplicate files in a given set of directories (man)
Path    : /usr/bin/fdupes
Version : 1.51
Type    : ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYS ...)
Help    : probably available with -h,--help
Repo    : Debian 8.9 (jessie) 
Home    : http://code.google.com/p/fdupes/ (pm)

jdupes  finds and performs actions upon duplicate files (man)
Path    : ~/executable/jdupes
Version : 1.5.1 (2016-11-01)
Type    : ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYS ...)
Home    : https://github.com/jbruchon/jdupes (doc)

rdfind  finds duplicate files (man)
Path    : /usr/bin/rdfind
Version : 1.3.4
Type    : ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYS ...)
Repo    : Debian 8.9 (jessie) 
Home    : http://rdfind.pauldreik.se/ (pm)

duff    duplicate file finder (man)
Path    : /usr/bin/duff
Version : 0.5.2
Type    : ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYS ...)
Repo    : Debian 8.9 (jessie) 
Home    : http://duff.sourceforge.net/ (pm)
```

Bes wishes ... cheers, drl

Answer (score 3):

Use return value of

```
diff file1 file2 >/dev/null
```

as it returns zero when files are the same and nonzero when files differ.

Compare the files in two nested `for` cycles. Something as:

```
for file1 in $(COMMAND)
do
    for file2 in $(COMMAND)
    do
        if ! diff "${file1}" "${file2}" > /dev/null 2>&1
        then
            echo "${file1} and ${file2} differ"
        fi
    done
done
```

Or, as Stéphane Chazelas suggested, you can simplify it:

```
for file1 in $(COMMAND)
do
    for file2 in $(COMMAND)
    do
        diff -q "${file1}" "${file2}"
    done
done
```

as `diff -q` prints the message from the first approach itself.

Comment: Don't use the `test` command (`[]`) when it's not necessary.

Comment: Use the double quotation on all variables when possible.

Comment: @Vlastimil: thank you, the test command syntax I didn't know and the quotation I forgot.

Comment: @Vlastimil BTW, the `do` and `then` on newline is a matter of style or is there any practical reason?

Comment: No problem mate. The `for do then` syntax you had correctly. Feel free to change it back. I just felt maybe you would like to see it differently. It's just a matter of style.

Comment: If you don't care about what the differences are, using `cmp` or `diff -q` would be a lot more efficient that redirecting the ouput of `diff` to /dev/null

Comment: This is computationally VERY inefficient! Not only is it `O(n^2)` with `n` being the number of files being compared, but the each individual `diff` is computationally unnecessary and computationally heavy. See my answer below.

Comment: @user1404316 you are right. But in the question there is explicitly mentioned that the number of files is less than 10. In this case, you don't care about effectivity. Upvoted your answer for using awk to compare cksums.

Answer (score 3):

You could do:

```
find foo* -name 'bar*Test.groovy' -type f -exec cksum {} + | sort
```

(assuming file paths don't contain newline characters) which would give you a checksum (and size) for each file, letting you easily see which are the same.

You can replace `cksum` with `md5sum`/`shasum`/`sha512sum`/`sha3sum` if available and you worry about potential checksum collisions.

Answer (score 1):

Since you aren't interested in what the differences are, and you want all files compared against each other the most computationally efficient (see *O-notation*) method is going to be to perform a single `md5sum` action on each file, sort the output by the `md5sum` and mark duplicates, which will be consecutive.

`find foo* -name bar*Test.groovy | md5sum | sort | \
     awk 'key==$1{print file " is identical to "$2}{key=$1;file=$2}'`

Answer (score 0):

Install fdupes package using below `yum install fdupes*`

Then use the below command to find the identical files or duplicate files means the files which having same content

```
fdupes path
```

In current path it will display all files which are identical or duplicate

Answer (score 0):

Use [rmlint](http://rmlint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and pipe the results of find to it:

```
find foo* -name "bar*Test.groovy" | rmlint -T duplicates -
```